# Is there a bug in the implementation of the Research Assistant badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, badges, tag-wiki

I was doing several tag wiki edits (both true tag wikis and excerpts) in [linguistics.se]. I saw the counter "Your badge progress" on the right sidebar increasing:

```
Your Badge Progress

Research Assistant
52 tag wiki edits (104% done)
```

Also, in my profile page, it says:

```
Congratulations!

You've earned
 Research Assistant
Track the next one
Let us pick
```

But ... clicking through on "Learn more" gives me ...

```
 Research Assistant
Edit 50 tag wikis.
jknappen
5,30211133

did not earn this badge
```

I waited for some time (about 30 minutes) and used forced reload of the pages. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Just about everything is cached here. Look again in a few hours, or tomorrow.

Comment: Ah!, the badge (and the hat I was hunting for) have just arrived. The first research assistant on the site.

Comment: @ale no cache in this case, just different schedules. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're tracking the badge, the profile page will say you earned it once you meet the criteria for it. However, the actual award process runs on a schedule and may not kick in right away. At the moment this is by design.